# Java: Pegar nome e número de série de celular conectado ao computador

Tags: java

Caros, em primeiro lugar: Essa não é uma questão envolvendo desenvolvimento Android.

Estou fazendo automação no java, e gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de guardar em strings o nome e o número de série do dispositivo ao conectá-lo via USB no computador. Atualmente faço isso manualmente entrando no ***"Meu computador > Selecionando o celular com botão direito > Propriedades"*** e então copiando essas informações.

Há alguma maneira de fazer isso via Java?

Desde já,

Obrigado!

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23469703/2556111)

Answer (score -1):

Fala Luís,

O serial é simples, é só chamar o build, exemplo:

```
String deviceSerial;

try {
   deviceSerial = (String) Build.class.getField("SERIAL").get(null);
 } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }

Log.d("serial", deviceSerial);
```

E pra pegar o nome, é um pouquinho mais complicado, exemplo:

```
public static String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize(model);
    }
    return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
}

private static String capitalize(String str) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
        return str;
    }
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    boolean capitalizeNext = true;

    StringBuilder phrase = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : arr) {
        if (capitalizeNext && Character.isLetter(c)) {
            phrase.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            capitalizeNext = false;
            continue;
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            capitalizeNext = true;
        }
        phrase.append(c);
    }

    return phrase.toString();
}
```

Ai pra chamar o resultado, você faz:

```
String deviceName = getDeviceName();
```

Abraços.

Comment: primeiramente, muito obrigado pela ajuda..!

Tentei o primeiro, para pegar o serialNumber, porém está retornando null...Eu simplesmente abri uma classe no java, importei o android pelo maven, e inseri essa string num system.out pra ver o que dava.

Será que eu deveria ter feito algo antes?

Comment: Estranho estar vindo como nula, alterei a minha resposta com um novo código pra pegar o serial, da uma conferida.